# XML to LINQ ElementAtOrDefault(x).elements for non-existant index

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an issue going on where in I need to pull an element after I have the elementAtOrDefault method. I am pretty sure what I am trying to do can also be implemented in some other way, may be I am just not aware. But below in the LINQ query I am trying

```
Dim extractDetails = From GradScoreRows In doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "gradeOr") _
        Select New RecordScoreDetails With _
        { _
        .Result = GradScoreRows .Descendants(ns + "score").Elements(ns + "results").Value, _
        .ResultComment = GradScoreRows .Descendants(ns + "score").Elements(ns + "resultComment").Value, _
        .ImpactedScore = GradScoreRows .Descendants(ns + "score").Elements(ns + "ImpactedScore").Value, _
        .SubjectACode = GradScoreRows .Descendants(ns + "factors").Descendants(ns + "factor").ElementAtOrDefault(0).Elements(ns + "code").Value, _
        .SubjectARank = GradScoreRows .Descendants(ns + "factors").Descendants(ns + "factor").ElementAtOrDefault(1).Elements(ns + "rank").Value, _
        }
```

The XML snippet I am trying to query is:

```
<gradeOr>
    <score>
           <results>Passed</results>
           <resultsComment>some comment</resultsComment>
           <impactedScore>Something impacted Score</impactedScore>
           <factors>
              <factor>
                  <code>A</code>
                  <rank>20</rank>
               </factor>
              <factor>
                   <code>B</code>
                   <rank>20</rank>
              </factor>
           </factors>
    </score>
</gradeOr>
```

The issue is that the factors section may not appear in every XML I receive. How would I deal with such a scenario?

I have tried using ElementsAt(x) without the default and obviously I hit the problem of the index being our of range for certain scenario's and when I use the default I run into object reference not set to an instance of an object issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way, but one way would be like this:

```vb
Dim extractDetails =
    From grade In doc...<gradeOr> 
    Let subjA = (From subj In grade.<score>.<factors>.<factor>).FirstOrDefault()
    Select New With {
        .Result = grade.<score>.<results>.Value,
        .ResultComment = grade.<score>.<resultsComment>.Value,
        .ImpactedScore = grade.<score>.<impactedScore>.Value,
        .SubjectACode = If(subjA IsNot Nothing, subjA.<code>.Value, Nothing),
        .SubjectARank = If(subjA IsNot Nothing, subjA.<rank>.Value, Nothing)
    }
```

This uses a subquery to find the first `<factor>`, if any, and checks if that was found when populating the properties.  I'm not very happy with the repeated `If()` statements, but it seems to work OK.

You will need to adjust to fit in with your classes and/or namespace, since I didn't have that information.  I'm also not entirely sure if this gets the correct elements for the `SubjectACode/Rank` properties, since I think your code pulls them from different `<factor>` elements, and I wasn't sure how the `A` values in your sample XML related to SubjectA.  Please clarify if I missed something.